# Idioms meaning "everybody"

Tags: idiomatic-language, names

I need help finding an idiom that means "everybody" in this context:

Three names in English make an expression that literally means “everyone,” usually in a negative sense. For example, Jane shouted at Julie, who had revealed Jane’s deepest secrets, “I did not want every …………, ………… and ………… to know what I told you.”

Comment: What research have you done that tells you that there *is* such an idiom?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: I believe you are looking for "every Tom, Dick and Harry". It would be nice if you would show what research you have already done, however. This site doesn't exist to do Carla's homework. Welcome to ELL.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is every Tom, Dick and Harry. It is an expression, which means you don't want your personal affairs to be known by just anyone, you want to keep them private. It is probably rather old-fashioned.